# Best (easiest) way to execute a function (with response) in another python thread?

Tags: python, ipc, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a little python script running on an raspberry pi (which is hooked up to detect if something is delivered to my mailbox) to send me a telegram message with a snapshot of my mailbox content.

Up until now this has been a single monolithic script which handled GPIO interaction (led lights and threaded_callbacks for reed_contacts), picamera and the telegram messaging.
But the telegram bot I was using ([telepot](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot)) is no longer supported. Which is why I am looking to incorporate another python telegram bot implementation ([python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)) as well as migrate the script to python3 since python2 has also been [discontinued](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

But in doing so, I think I will need to split up the script, since the python-telegram-bot does not run non-blocking in a calling script. 
In my old script I could still continue with the main program after calling the `MessageLoop(bot, handler).run_as_thread()`(spawning a separate background thread for update checking). But with the python-telegram-bot no instruction after 
`updater.start_polling() updater.idle()` is evaluated till the bot is stopped.

I think my best bet in migrating the script is splitting it into two separate scripts which communicate with each other. One script which handles the interaction with picamera & gpio and another one soley for user interaction via telegram.

For example, the command to request a picture of the actual mailbox contents is received by the telegram_script. The telegram_script should then tell the low_level_script to execute the `capture()` function and wait for the return/result of this function (to make sure the picture is saved/updated before the  telegram_script tries to send it).

My question is, how do I communicate between the two? 
What is the best/easiest way in python to execute a function in the low_level_script with the result returned to the telegram_script?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you want to structure your system. If you have one script that runs on 2 process using the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) you could [a pipe or a queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) to communicate between them.

If you have two very independent scripts, maybe you can look then at using a [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) with a Unix socket name.